# Datetime column to list column of parts

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr, purrr

I have a tibble with a date column:

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1489494191.81966, 1489494125.153, 
    1489494058.48633, 1489493991.81966, 1489493925.153, 1489493858.48633, 
    1489493791.81966, 1489493725.153, 1489493658.48633, 1489493591.81966
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = "date", class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

df

# A tibble: 10 × 1
                  date
                <dttm>
1  2017-03-14 13:23:11
2  2017-03-14 13:22:05
3  2017-03-14 13:20:58
4  2017-03-14 13:19:51
5  2017-03-14 13:18:45
6  2017-03-14 13:17:38
7  2017-03-14 13:16:31
8  2017-03-14 13:15:25
9  2017-03-14 13:14:18
10 2017-03-14 13:13:11
```

which I would like to tranform in into a list column with lists of the parts (year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds), something like:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 1
                     result
                     <list>
1  list(2017,3,14,13,23,11)
2  list(2017,3,14,13,22,5)
3  list(2017,3,14,13,20,58)
4  list(2017,3,14,13,19,51)
5  list(2017,3,14,13,18,45)
6  list(2017,3,14,13,17,38)
7  list(2017,3,14,13,16,31)
8  list(2017,3,14,13,15,25)
9  list(2017,3,14,13,14,18)
10 list(2017,3,14,13,13,11)
```

I've tried a bunch of string split strategies but they are very inefficient (actual df is massive). The components of the list need to be integer or numeric in the end.

Is there a clever way?

**EDIT:**

This is what I'm doing now but it doesn't seem to scale that well:

```
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  transmute(y = year(date),
            m = month(date),
            d = day(date),
            hh = hour(date),
            mm = minute(date),
            ss = second(date)
         ) %>%
  by_row(c, .to = "result") %>%
  select(result)

# A tibble: 10 × 1
       result
       <list>
1  <list [6]>
2  <list [6]>
3  <list [6]>
4  <list [6]>
5  <list [6]>
6  <list [6]>
7  <list [6]>
8  <list [6]>
9  <list [6]>
10 <list [6]>
```

Comment: I guess `df$res <- strsplit(as.character(df$date), " |-|:")` could be a start

Answer (score 0):

You can use `library(lubridate)`:

```
library(lubridate)

y <- year(df$date)
m <- month(df$date)
d <- day(df$date)
h <- hour(df$date)
min <- minute(df$date)
s <- as.integer(second(df$date))
```

and then combine to a list.

```
res <- lapply(1:length(y), function(x){

  return(c(y[x], d[x], d[x], h[x], min[x], s[x]))

})

tibble::tibble(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line of code with `data.table` as:

`DT[, unclass(as.POSIXlt(date))][, .(year+1900, mon, mday, hour, min, sec)]`

Convert your `data.frame` to `data.table` and date to POSIXlt format.

```
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[, unclass(as.POSIXlt(date))][, ':=' (year=year+1900, mon=mon+1, sec=floor(sec)) ][, .(year, mon, mday, hour, min, sec)]
```

This chains the operations so the result looks like:

```
   year mon mday hour min sec
 1: 2017   3   14    7  23  11
 2: 2017   3   14    7  22   5
 3: 2017   3   14    7  20  58
 4: 2017   3   14    7  19  51
 5: 2017   3   14    7  18  45
 6: 2017   3   14    7  17  38
 7: 2017   3   14    7  16  31
 8: 2017   3   14    7  15  25
 9: 2017   3   14    7  14  18
10: 2017   3   14    7  13  11
```

This is probably the fastest way in R to process millions of records splitting the date in the way you intended.